# Why is Foundation global sometimes undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

Im developing a HTML application with the following structure:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- other head elements -->
    <script src="jquery.js?_v=3736f12"></script>
    <script src="error.js?_v=291bb66"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- other body elements -->
    <script src="foundation.js?_v=880a16f"></script>
    <script src="my_lib.js?_v=1c3b21e"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What `error.js` does is that it listens for window.onerror event and when it is triggered it sends error message via ajax to the server to notify us developers. This way we know when users javascript complaints about something.

`my_lib.js` is a quite big library that does a lots of tasks and it often builds on Foundation framework and theirs javascript library that is included just before my_lib.js in the HTML structure.

Now I can get to my question. These days we are getting errors similar to those:

- TypeError: window.Foundation is undefined
- TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.Foundation.Abide')
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Dropdown' of undefined (in code Foundation.Dropdown)

Those errors usually come from uses of foundations global `Foundation` inside my_lib.js and from various userAgents, more often from mobile devices, but not exclusively. Timing of the errors is usually before ready event or sometimes between ready and load events. The crazy thing is that those errors do not come always from the same users (not even if they are twice on the same page), they come just sometimes and we weren't able to reproduce single one.

Im quite sure, that we are never setting `Foundation` to undefined explicitly and if we were, than that would be a onload problem in every blowser.

This made me question if foundation.js is always evaluated before evaluating my_lib.js. From my reading of posts here on SO I understand that  tags are evaluated in order and are waiting for each other (we never use async or defer).

Only another clue is that I was able to get from the server logs is that those errors occur usually when user is entering/reloading our site after some time of inactivity. For example after loging in or on refresh after long inactivity while still logged in.

Does anybody have an idea why is this hapenning?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: i think the plugin are initiated before the library is loaded

Comment: better initiate all your plugins when all the rendering is complete

Comment: I would recommend you to give attribute `defer` to the script elements. It will download JS while parsing HTML (which can increase page load speed) and also guarentee to execute scripts in the order that they appear in the document. BTW: why don't you put `script` at the end of document, like foundation or my_lib?

Comment: @madalinivascu that is imho way too late and unnecesary, dont you think?

Comment: @debute yes I could try defer, but I read that it is not supported everywhere. We put script tags that need DOM ready just before </body>, jquery and error.js does not need that, so thay can be executed sooner..

Comment: @Walkerr47 the only problem with compatibility can be IE, because `defer` is supported in IE >= 10. Another solution, but I think it can be too late, is to use require.js. It is great library which you can be always sure that required scripts are loaded before executing your code. But it can be hard to transform your scripts, if you already have running big application.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a classical race condition, when your code is executed the library might or might not be loaded, if not your getting back undefined.

To avoid this before you execute any code which relies on library make sure that for example this event was triggerd.

```
(document.readyState === 'complete') {
  // good to go!
}
```

Comment: So you are saing that when I have two script tags with different js files it is not guaranteed that the first one is ready when the second one is starting execution?

Comment: Strictly spoken this should'nt happen script tags are loaded sequentially one after another, as long as you don't give them any async tags or similiar. Still this is not very reliable depending on user connection and other factors. You don't know what's exactly happening in your library. That's why it's saver to wait for the document.readyState